# PHP is converting decimal to exponential value

Tags: php, rounding

I have the following piece of code:

```
$price = 0.000001;
$price = round(floatval($price), 6);
echo $price;
```

I don't understand why php is showing $price as 1.0E-6 instead of 0.000001. DUe to this am getting validation errors.

What's wrong with the code.

Comment: It does not convert anything, don't confuse representation with the actual data. It's unlikely you have a validation issue caused by default `echo` format but by something else.

Comment: If you leave it to PHP, PHP will choose a string format based on the number it's getting. If you want a specific format use `number_format()`. [Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Comment: To put it out in code: [1.0e-6 === 0.000001 <- Link](http://3v4l.org/X2aUL)

Comment: don't use floats for price...